# CancelledKeyException and ClosedChannelException in Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

I keep getting `CancelledKeyExpection` and `ClosedChannelException` with my Spark program. I tried to remedy it by increasing `spark.network.timeout` to 600 and `spark.akka.frameSize` to 1280. Moreover, I have allocated more than enough memory to each executor and driver. Also, I'm using the latest version of Spark, that is Spark 1.5. I even tried with 1.4, but got the same error. So, what could be the problem? Its driving me nuts! The error is shown below.

```
java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException
        at org.apache.spark.network.nio.ConnectionManager.run(ConnectionManager.scala:461)
        at org.apache.spark.network.nio.ConnectionManager$$anon$7.run(ConnectionManager.scala:193)
15/09/16 16:27:38 INFO nio.ConnectionManager: Removing ReceivingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(bigdata-03.cluster,50585)
15/09/16 16:27:38 INFO nio.ConnectionManager: Removing SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(bigdata-03.cluster,50585)
15/09/16 16:27:38 ERROR nio.SendingConnection: Exception while reading SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(bigdata-03.cluster,50585)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureReadOpen(SocketChannelImpl.java:257)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:300)
        at org.apache.spark.network.nio.SendingConnection.read(Connection.scala:421)
        at org.apache.spark.network.nio.ConnectionManager$$anon$9.run(ConnectionManager.scala:259)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/09/16 16:27:38 ERROR nio.ConnectionManager: Exception while sending message.
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureReadOpen(SocketChannelImpl.java:257)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:300)
        at org.apache.spark.network.nio.SendingConnection.read(Connection.scala:421)
        at org.apache.spark.network.nio.ConnectionManager$$anon$9.run(ConnectionManager.scala:259)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Tried solution at http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Cancelled-Key-Exceptions-on-Massive-Join-td18967.html, but still no luck!